# Collating total CPU time spent on inlined copies of the same template function, across multiple call sites

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, perf

I would like to see how much total CPU time a process is spending on a particular function (or methods of a class) that can get called across different paths of execution, and thus would appear under different call stacks using perf. Is there a command, script or tool that would allow me to filter or collate this information in an easily digestible form?

In particular, I'm interested in how much time is collectively being spent by instances of std::unordered_map, which may or not make things trickier.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is a template class whose functions usually get inlined at their call sites.  There's no connection in the machine code itself between separate instances of it.  So that's a totally different problem from totalling up "self" time from multiple callers to an actual non-inlined function that actually exists in machine code.

Comment: I retitled your question.  For functions that don't get inlined, there should be a "self" time somewhere if you look at your perf record results *without* breaking them out by call tree.  (Or at least, counts for the `cycles` event, which loosely correlates with time spent as far as that's even meaningful in a deep out-of-order exec CPU.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the clarification, but I'm still confused. If the template functions are inlined, how come I can still see entries of, e.g. `std::unordered_map` `operator[]` in the output of perf, then?

Also, I appreciate the retitling, but even though the particular case of inlined template functions might not apply to how I originally phrased it, I am still interested in how to do the general case, which might attract more feedback.

Comment: debug info can still map machine instructions to source lines / functions.  So it's plausible there could be a way to do this, aggregating on source-level line numbers / function names instead of just doing that mapping after aggregating based on machine-code address.